# Upload image to facebook fan page using API

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am trying to upload an image through my application with Facebook Graph API to an album of my fan page. Although I provide the albumID like a parameter for uploading the image, it is uploaded in an album named APPLICATION_NAME Photos on my own profile. The album of the fan page stays empty. I tried also with sending the pageID of my fan page instead of albumID, but the result is the same. The code I use for the upload is:

```
$fb_pfoto = $facebook->api('/' . $albumID . '/photos','POST', array(
       'access_token' => $session['access_token'],
       'message'      => 'Caption',
       'source'       => '@' . realpath( '/path/to/image.jpg' )
    ));
```

Please give me ideas how can I upload the image to the fan page and not to my own profile album.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Don't know if this would help but maybe you need to request `manage_pages` extended permission and then use returned page access_token for posting pictures. You can read briefly about this process [here](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/api#impersonation).

Then you can try these links with page access token for posting photos:

```
/me/photos
/<page_id>/photos
/<album_id>/photos
```

Comment: Thanks very much for the answer. From what I read from your link, this permission allows me to access user's fan page. What I need to achieve is to upload the content to one single fan page which is administrated by me.

Comment: @serg brother can you provide me some example. How I can post single or multiple images on customer facebook company page ? and also tell me How I can manage If customer have multiple facebook page ?

Answer (score 12):

Here  is the script for uploading photos on your Facebook Fanpage:

```
<html>
<head>
<title>WebSpeaks.in | Upload images to Facebook</title>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1">
</head>

<body>
<?php
require_once 'library/facebook.php';
$facebook = new Facebook(array(
 'appId'  => $app_id,,
 'secret' => $app_secret,
 'fileUpload' => true
));


//It can be found at https://developers.facebook.com/tools/access_token/
$access_token = '<Your access token>';

$params = array('access_token' => $access_token);

//The id of the fanpage
$fanpage = '330299184793';

//The id of the album
$album_id ='10150418901414794';

//Replace arvind07 with your Facebook ID
$accounts = $facebook->api('/arvind07/accounts', 'GET', $params);

foreach($accounts['data'] as $account) {
 if( $account['id'] == $fanpage || $account['name'] == $fanpage ){
  $fanpage_token = $account['access_token'];
 }
}


$valid_files = array('image/jpeg', 'image/png', 'image/gif');

if(isset($_FILES) && !empty($_FILES)){
 if( !in_array($_FILES['pic']['type'], $valid_files ) ){
  echo 'Only jpg, png and gif image types are supported!';
 }else{
  #Upload photo here
  $img = realpath($_FILES["pic"]["tmp_name"]);

  $args = array(
   'message' => 'This photo was uploaded via WebSpeaks.in',
   'image' => '@' . $img,
   'aid' => $album_id,
   'no_story' => 1,
   'access_token' => $fanpage_token
  );

  $photo = $facebook->api($album_id . '/photos', 'post', $args);
  if( is_array( $photo ) && !empty( $photo['id'] ) ){
   echo '<p><a target="_blank" href="http://www.facebook.com/photo.php?fbid='.$photo['id'].'">Click here to watch this photo on Facebook.</a></p>';
  }
 }
}

?>
 <!-- Form for uploading the photo -->
 <div class="main">
  <p>Select a photo to upload on Facebook Fan Page</p>
  <form method="post" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>" enctype="multipart/form-data">
  <p>Select the image: <input type="file" name="pic" /></p>
  <p><input class="post_but" type="submit" value="Upload to my album" /></p>
  </form>
 </div>
</body>
</html>
```

You can watch [**complete tutorial here**](http://www.webspeaks.in/2011/12/upload-photos-to-facebook-fan-page.html).

Comment: I'm afraid this code sample does not actually work Arvind. Whilst it will return the "uploaded" photo ID, when one tries to access the photo it says "The content is currently unavailable."

Comment: The access_token expires after two hours ( https://developers.facebook.com/tools/access_token/ )

Answer (score 4):

My best guess would be one of two possibilties:

- that your app does not have permission to upload to that album.  If you request /me/albums using the pages access token, it will list the albums associated with that page.  The is a can_upload field for each album which is either true or false (specific to the access token you are using).

  **or**
- You are using an access token associated with your personal account, and not the page the album belongs to.  Here is some information on how to authenticate as a page rather then the user who owns the page: http://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/pages/

Comment: David, this is one of the best insights I could find on this topic (which like many others, I am struggling with..). I followed your steps to look for the 'can_upload' field and it shows up as 'false' for all the albums, including the 'Wall Photos'. Fans are able to upload photos to the page wall thru the usual Photo/Video tab on the Wall. All such Photos are uploaded to the 'Wall Photos'. However, the can_upload field shows up as 'false' and I am assuming that a multipart/form post thru graph api (pageId/photos?access_token=...) is not going to work. How to create album with can_upload=true?

Comment: Facebook says that only Albums created by your app will have can_upload = true, but I have found this not to be true across the board.  The simplest way to get it to work is to post your photo without the aid field.  By default Facebook will create an album named AppName's Photo's if it doesn't exist, and add the photo there.  Also, I would recommend requesting just plain "/me" using the access_token you to make sure you are indeed using the page token and not your own user access token.

Comment: Many thanks David. (all this though, does not allow you to post a photo to a page or a user-wall as your self. Unless I misunderstood, the points above are around being able to upload photo to the page as the 'page', right ?).

Comment: You understood correctly.  I was referring to uploading a photo to an album you own.  It could be the page upload to its albums, or you uploading to your own albums.

To post an photo to someone elses wall is a different situation.  I do not know how to do that.  I just tested it on facebook directly, and it seemed that the photo went to an album called "Photos Of [TargetPage]".  I wasn't able to find a link to this album though and it appeared strangely on the pages feed (there was no thumbnail for the image, just a message that a photo was posted with a link).

Answer (score 1):

I had the same hard problem that when I try to share a photo to a page ,I posted it as a user not as page .And when I try to post it in an album the photo posted in my profile.
But thanks to [thefreeman](https://stackoverflow.com/users/920113/thefreeman) I solved the problem
As thefreeman said ,
You must first take manage_pages permission
**then get Page Access Token as mentioned [here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/access-tokens#pagetokens)**
then use this token instead of user access token in your app or website
finaly ,to post the photos on the page wall"me/photos"
or to post it in specific album in the page use "{album-id}/photos"