# Post photo to a specific page and album

Tags: facebook-c#-sdk, photos

I'm trying to use the C# Facebook SDK to post a photo to a page that I am a content creator for.

```
dynamic parameters = new ExpandoObject();
        parameters.message = txtMessage.Text;
        parameters.source = new FacebookMediaObject
        {
            ContentType = "image/jpeg",
            FileName = Path.GetFileName(ofd.FileName)
        }.SetValue(File.ReadAllBytes(ofd.FileName));
```

When I try a path like the following it gives me an error that says (OAuthException - #2500) Unknown path components: /ALBUM_ID/photos

```
 fb.PostTaskAsync("PAGE_ID/ALBUM_ID/photos", parameters);
```

When I try a path like the following it posts the photo to my own profile.

```
 fb.PostTaskAsync("PAGE_ID/photos", parameters);
```

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 2):

You’re just using the wrong path – you have to post to `/ALBUM_ID/photos` directly, not to /page/album/photos and not to /page/photos either.

See also: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/album/

Comment: Yes, thank you for pointing that out.  Also what I didn't know is that you have to use the access token from your list of accounts for the specific page you are trying to post to as opposed to the token you use to access your own stuff as mentioned in number 4 in this post.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3778424/upload-image-to-facebook-fan-page-using-api