# Upload image to facebook fan page using Graph API

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, upload, photo, facebook-page

I am trying to upload an image through my application with Facebook Graph API to an album of my fan page. Although I provide the albumID like a parameter for uploading the image, it is uploaded in an album named to my application name Photos on my own profile. The album of the fan page stays empty. I tried also with sending the pageID of my fan page instead of albumID, but the result is the same. 
I thought there is a problem with access token but with same accessstoken i can post links to page.

The code I use for the upload is:

```
    $args = array(
        'access_token'  => $access_token,
        'message'       => "$baslik",
        "source" => '@' . realpath($file)
    );                      

$post_id = $facebook->api("/$page_id/photos","post",$args);
```

Please give me ideas how can I upload the image to the fan page and not to my own profile album.

Comment: I don’t see you providing an album id anywhere in your code.

Comment: CBroe at this code i didn't. but instead of that $page_id i've written albumID but still same thing happened.here https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/page/ at photos section it says that we can publish with posting to PAGE_ID/photos but i'm unsuccessful at that

Comment: Do you have the right permissions? Are you trying to post photos as the page itself, or as a user? If the latter, do the page’s settings allow posts by users?

Comment: I have right permissions. i am trying to post as page. I can share links as page with the same APP without any problem. Also i've tried to use a content creator and admin but still can't post

Comment: @r10: Have you solved this problem?

Comment: Yes i solved it. I thought there is only 1 access token but i've discovered that every page generates a unique access token for each user.(it's different then the one which you use for posting links) I used that new access token and it worked.

Comment: almost forgot. after using this system for a few days, FB delete all my fan pages without giving any reason. so, be careful about it.

Comment: hey I know it has been a quite long time but do you know why facebook deleted your pages? because I am trying to write a contest for my fan page.

Answer (score 0):

I think you havent got Manage Permission.

Check this for more info : [Upload image to facebook fan page using API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3778424/upload-image-to-facebook-fan-page-using-api?rq=1#comment4008765_3781094)