# Facebook Application To Post To A Fan Page

Tags: java, facebook

I am trying to make a simple Application on facebook.

There will only be one user using this, me.

Say I have 10 photos to upload everyday, I thought i'll make an application that will simply take every image in a directory and simply upload it to a page. A Fan page assume "X"

I started out by making an app in developer.facebook.com, say "X app".
Then I got the facebook4j library and tried posting a status as the page, using manage_pages permission.

I am stuck at many ends in this attempt and just wanted to ensure this is the right way to do it, or am I doing something enitrely wrong perhaps?

Answer (score 1):

There is already a complete answer to this question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3778424/upload-image-to-facebook-fan-page-using-api) (even with the needed source code).

However, if you need to do this automatically, create a PHP script that will take N new photos from a directory, upload them to your Facebook fan page and moving or deleting them when they are successfully online.

Then just use crontab on your server to call this script everyday at a chosen hour.